# How to close Server-Sent Events events

Tags: javascript, html, server-sent-events

I want to know how to close a server-sent events via JavaScript. Below is my dummy code:

```
var ser=new EventSource("path");
ser.onmessage=function(ev){
if(!ev)
   //want to close HERE!!
else
   console.log(ev);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/EventSource#Method_overview - the `.close()` method?

Comment: sorry i was writing Close() all this time..fixed

Answer (score 11):

The correct way to close a server side event is with the `close` method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/EventSource#Method_overview

So you'd use:

```
var ser = new EventSource("path");
ser.onmessage = function (ev) {
    if (!ev)
       ser.close();
    else
       console.log(ev);
};
```

JavaScript is case sensitive, so you can't use `.Close()`, as it's a different thing than `.close()` and will be undefined in this case.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the way that I found worked best for me

```
var eventSource = new EventSource("path");
eventSource.onerror = eventSourceErrorFunction;
var eventSourceErrorFunction = function(event)
{
        if (event.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            that.eventSource.close();
            console.log("Event Source Closed");
        }  
}
```